# The most negative number which is greater than -DBL_MAX

Tags: c++

I represent a "physically impossible" value with the most negative possible to represent on the computer.

```
#include <float.h>
double physically_impossible = -DBL_MAX;
```

The test for this works nicely

```
if( physically_impossible == -DBL_MAX )
    cout << " OK, detected impossible value";
else
    cout << " failed to detect impossible value";
cout << endl;
```

giving

```
 OK, detected impossible value
```

But when I try to test for a very small but "physically possible" number something goes horribly wrong.

```
double physically_impossible_plus_one = 1 - DBL_MAX;
cout << "physically_impossible " << physically_impossible << " physically_impossible_plus_one " << physically_impossible_plus_one;
if( physically_impossible < physically_impossible_plus_one )
    cout << " OK, detected impossible value plus one";
else
    cout << " failed to detect impossible value plus one";
cout << endl;
```

gives

```
physically_impossible -1.79769e+308 physically_impossible_plus_one -1.79769e+308 failed to detect impossible value plus one
```

As Karoly Horvath pointed out, this fails because of the limited precision. what I need is the most negative number which is greater than -DBL_MAX

( Motivation:  I want to divide numbers ( not NAN which raises exceptions and triggers asserts ) into physically possible and physically impossible with the minimum reduction in the usable range of physically possible numbers. )

Comment: Why not represent the value with negative infinity or NaN?

Comment: NaN is definitely what I'd use.

Comment: I think this question is ill-posed. Which number is just larger than -DBL_MAX depends on the representation and that can be different depending on whether the comparison is done in a 80 or 64 bit register, both of which the compiler is allowed to use ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `DBL_MAX` and the next biggest number is a power of two (because the difference in the two mantissas is exactly 1). So at program start-up you can search for the smallest power of two `p` such that `DBL_MAX - p != DBL_MAX`, and `-(DBL_MAX - p)` will be your smallest usable value:

```
double p = 1.0 ;
while (DBL_MAX - p == DBL_MAX) p *= 2.0 ;
double smallest_usable_value = -(DBL_MAX - p) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant answer.  ( While everyone else is trying to decide whether they like my question or not, you actually did the work and provided the answer without worrying about all that.  Seems to me that is what a Q&A site is about: answers to questions. )

Comment: @ravensport: not this Q&A site, unfortunately! But if it's opinions that you want, look no further.

Answer (score 3):

The floating point representation has limited precision. Adding one to -1.79769e+308 obviously won't change it.

It's not a problem, don't worry about it. If the value represents any physical property, well, getting near to DBL_MAX means you're doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: It most certainly is a problem if this is his goal. He'll need an alternative, not to just ignore it...

Comment: We don't know whether he's got a reason to add one to his value; the fact that he's trying to do it implies yes.

Comment: So, yes, I get the point about precision.  I think, therefore, what I need is the most negative  number which is greater than -DBL_MAX

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: and common sense dictates a huge NO. Sry, there are no legal reasons to do that.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I didn't say they would be _good_ reasons. I'm just saying that the OP is attempting this for a reason, so we should correct that and give him another way to realise his goal, rather than just saying "ignore it"!

Comment: My motivation may or may not make sense.  It does for me.  Whatever, my question is perfectly clear and TonyH has provided an excellent answer.

Comment: @ravenspoint: I'm not a fan of helping someone do something stupid.

Comment: Not being a fan permits you to be rude?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to use an extreme number to represent "nothingness" is not a great idea and this is why: by definition you're at the extremes of your floating-point type's precision bounds and so you're very limited in what you can do around that value.

I would strongly recommend using a value that was invented for this purpose, such as `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`. Note that you won't be able to do *any* arithmetic on it.

Answer (score 0):

Without commenting on whether I find this a very good approach... you will need to add something that is *at most* 16 digits (actually slightly less than 16, since 2<sup>53</sup> is 9.007e+15) smaller than `DBL_MAX`, or whatever value you add will be insignificant and "disappear".

`1e+292` is 16 digits smaller than the "typical" `DBL_MAX` of 1.7e+308, so any number close to that should work for what you want. Proof of concept:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    double pi = -DBL_MAX;
    double pi_plus = -DBL_MAX + 1e+292;

    printf("%g\n", pi);
    printf("%g\n", pi_plus);
    printf("%i\n", pi == pi_plus);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-1.79769e+308
-1.79769e+308
0
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d958d2947f35dd1)